# Sorting string based on substring

Tags: java

I have list of strings like this

> > B2B16, A1B01, S1B32, A1B23, B1B44

I want to sort the order of string based on the substring(3,4) of each 5 string. I want to sort the string based on substring (3,4) that has 1,0,2,3,4 starting from small to big.

Expected result:

> > A1B01, B2B16, A1B23, S1B32, B1B44

I tried this:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(ssss -> ssss.substring(3, 4)).thenComparing(ssss -> ssss.subtring(3, 4), Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: define "doesn't work", is there an error message? wrong result? doesn't compile? (due to typos like "subtring" for example?)

Comment: `myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(3)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit old fashioned and not used to Java8, but I would resolve this as follows:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
  @Override
  public int compare(String s1,
                     String s2)
  {
    return (s1.substring(3, 5).compareTo(s2.substring(3, 5)));
  }
}

myList.sort(new MyComparator());
```

Since all strings have a length of 5, you might also use `substring(3)` instead of `substring(3, 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice way to do it in [this site](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-use-the-comparatorcomparing-method-java-8.cfm), basically the line that you want to add in your program is this one here: `Collections.sort(myList, Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.substring(3, 4)));`

Answer (score 0):

In jave 8, you can try this code

```
list.sort((a,b) -> a.substring(3,4).compareTo(b.substring(3,4)));
```